# Javascript getting loading time of each iframe source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a code that reads urls from a text file and puts them in a iframe one after another. I want to calculate the loading time of each page. I do that by marking the time before the iframe starts to load the url, and mark the time right aftrer its loaded. After load minus Before load gives me the loading time of each page.

```
    $.get("text.txt", function (data) {
        var array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/) 
        var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();    
        var loadTimes = [];
    $('#1').on('load', function () {
        loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime());           
        $('#1').attr('src', array.pop()); 
            $.each(loadTimes, function (index, value) {             
                var result = (value - beforeLoad) / 1000;       
                $("#loadingtime" + index).html(result);
            }); 
    }).attr('src', array.pop());
});
```

Problem here - before load time. I cant figure out how to mark the time before EACH url starts loading. In the code above beforeload value is a time value before ALL sources are loaded, where i want it to be changing every time a new source gets put into iframe. Any suggestions how i do this?

Edit: fixed it!

```
   $.get("imones.txt", function (data) {
        var array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/) 
        var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();    
        var loadTimes = [];
            var beforeTimes = [];               
        $('#frame_id').on('load', function () {                                 
            beforeTimes.push(beforeLoad);
            loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime()); 
            $('#frame_id').attr('src', array.pop());
                $.each(loadTimes, function (index, value) { 
                    var result = (value - beforeTimes[index]) / 1000;
                        if (result < 0) {
                            result = result * (-1);
                        }   
                    $("#loadingtime" + index).html(result);
                    beforeLoad = value;
                });
        }).attr('src', array.pop());
    });
```

Not sure what i did there, but this works for me, gonna analyze it now. I made an array of that stores correct before load times of each page.

Comment: Your code example here has some errors. The first function definition function (data) { never closes

Comment: thanks i eddit the post

Comment: FYI, ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z])

Comment: hmm ill change it but thats not the issue in my code, the functionality works fine but i just cant get the before load time of each source.. I can get the after load time of each source but not the before load time

Comment: Is there more source you can share? It's not clear what you are referencing to by the id '#1' and where you are actually creating iFrames. Is it just one iframe and it keeps triggering a new load when you reset the src attribute with a new url in the first 'load' event listener?

Answer (score 1):

```
var loadTimes = {};
$('#1').data('time', (new Date()).getTime()).on('load', function() {
  var $this = $(this), time = (new Date()).getTime();
  loadTimes[$this.attr('src')] = time - $this.data('time');
  $this.data('time', time);
  if (array.length == 0) {
    //end of load loadTimes contents with time of load each url
  } else $this.attr('src', array.pop());
}).attr('src', array.pop());
```

Comment: if you want to have plain array with loading time use `loadTimes.push(time - $this.data('time'))` instead `loadTimes[$this.attr('src')] = time - $this.data('time')`

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily store the new beforeLoad time temporarily, compute last load time, copy over new beforeLoad time.

```
$.get("text.txt", function (data) {
  var array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/); 
  var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();    
  var loadTimes = [];

  $('#1').on('load', function () {

    var nextBeforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
    loadTimes.push(nextBeforeLoad);       

    $.each(loadTimes, function (index, value) {             
        var result = (value - beforeLoad) / 1000;       
        $("#loadingtime" + index).html(result);
      }); 

    beforeLoad = nextBeforeLoad;
    $('#1').attr('src', array.pop()); 

  }).attr('src', array.pop());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var links = [
    'http://google.com',
    'http://yahoo.com'
]

$(links).each(function (i) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('t1', (new Date()).getTime());
    iframe.setAttribute('src', links[i]);
    iframe.onload = function () {
        var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log('Load Time: ' + ( t2 - parseInt(this.getAttribute('t1'))));
    }
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.get("text.txt", function (data) {
        var array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/) 
        var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();    
        var loadTimes = [];
            var beforeTimes = [];               
        $('#frame_id').on('load', function () {                                 
            beforeTimes.push(beforeLoad);
            loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime()); 
            $('#frame_id').attr('src', array.pop());
                $.each(loadTimes, function (index, value) { 
                    var result = (value - beforeTimes[index]) / 1000;
                        if (result < 0) {
                            result = result * (-1);
                        }   
                    $("#loadingtime" + index).html(result);
                    beforeLoad = value;
                });
        }).attr('src', array.pop());
    });
```